# How to sum multiple cell of a same column based on another column and display in another column?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to calculate sum of the cell values of same column based on another column. and display it in another column. for example,(in the below table) or [click here to see table image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByJTZfsDbET_eEQxLVRMN2ZEWE0/view?usp=sharing)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
  AccountType || AccountName || Amount || TotalByAccountType
-------------------------------------------------------------
   Type1      ||   name1     ||  200   || 
   Type1      ||   name2     ||  200   ||      400
---------------------------------------- ---------------------
   Type2      ||   name3     ||  200   || 
   Type2      ||   name4     ||  200   ||      600
   Type2      ||   name5     ||  200   || 
---------------------------------------- ---------------------
   Type3      ||   name6     ||  200   ||      200
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

there are four column (Account Type, Account Name, Amount, Total By Account Type).
 i am getting 1st three fields but not 4th one (Total By Account Type). 
TotalByAccountType = sum of Amount where accountType is same.
[for type2: The Sum of Amount of (name3 + name4 + name5) = 200 + 200 + 200 = 600].

I am new to sql server. Any help will be appreciated. I want TotalByAccountType. any suggestions?

Comment: This kind of result is better done on the presentation layer rather than in the database layer

Comment: thnx for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the query, you can use:

```
SELECT AccountType,
    AccountName,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountType) AS TotalByAccountType
FROM UnknownTableName
ORDER BY  AccountType,
    AccountName
```

This will give you results like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| AccountType | AccountName | Amount | TotalByAccountType |
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| Type1       | name1       |    200 |                400 |
| Type1       | name2       |    200 |                400 |
| Type2       | name3       |    200 |                600 |
| Type2       | name4       |    200 |                600 |
| Type2       | name5       |    200 |                600 |
| Type3       | name6       |    200 |                200 |
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
```

If you want to eliminate the "extras" in `TotalByAccountType`, that's considered a display issue, not a database issue.  You'll need to fix it in your report software or application.